# Declaring literal dates in lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, nunit

I'm currently developping an simple engine which generates lamda expressions from different classes (using reflexion and expression factories).

I have an issue trying to make some unit tests on my engine.

I use my engine to generate a lambda expression, then I compare the generated lambda with a "hand made" lambda expression. The problem is when I use a DateTime in my lambda expression. The lambda generated with reflection contains an "hard coded" date, whereas in the "hand made" lambda expression, I must use a "new DateTime(...)".

So the unit test fails with the following message (I cut the message to keep only the interresting part) :

> Expected: < x => (...) AndAlso (x.Date <= new DateTime(2015, 1, 1)))>
>
> But was:  < x => (...) AndAlso (x.Date <= 01/01/2015 00:00:00))>

My assert is the following :

```
Assert.AreEqual(expectedWhere, request.Filter);
```

Where "expectedWhere" is the "hand made" lambda and "request.Filter" is the generated lambda.

---

Is there a solution ([like in VB.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711653(v=vs.71).aspx)) to create my lambda expression like that :

```
Expression<Func<Model, bool>> expectedWhere = x => (...) && (x.Date <= [01/01/2015 00:00:00])
```

I already test to use an external variable, DateTime.Now, or a constant (not managed by the .NET framework).

---

### EDIT :

This is a simple fiddle showing my problem : https://dotnetfiddle.net/fKccY3

Code :

```
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Model), "x");
var property = Expression.Property(param, "Date");
ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(new DateTime(2015, 1, 1), typeof(DateTime));

Expression finalExpression = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(property, constant);

var tree = Expression.Lambda<Func<Model, bool>>(finalExpression, param);
Console.WriteLine(tree);

Expression<Func<Model, bool>> handMaidExpression = x => x.Date == new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);

Console.WriteLine(handMaidExpression);
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "generate a lambda expression"? Do you mean "generate an expression tree"? They're very different things... a lambda expression is an element of C# syntax... It would be helpful if you could show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you really mean you want to generate an appropriate expression tree with a `ConstantExpression` in, I think you'll have trouble doing that with an actual lambda expression. However, you could construct the relevant expression tree reasonably easily by constructing an expression tree for the *rest* of it with a lambda expression, and doing the rest manually. Here's a short but complete example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<Model, bool>> original = x => x.Name == "Fred";
        var parameter = original.Parameters[0];
        var dateClause = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(
            Expression.Property(parameter, "Date"),
            Expression.Constant(new DateTime(2015, 1, 1), typeof(DateTime)));
        var combined = Expression.AndAlso(original.Body, dateClause);
        var tree = Expression.Lambda<Func<Model, bool>>(combined, parameter);
        Console.WriteLine(tree);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
x => ((x.Name == "Fred") AndAlso (x.Date <= 01/01/2015 00:00:00))
```

You could fairly easily build this into a utility method if you need it in multiple places.

Comment: This is exactly what I used to generate the expression tree using reflection. The problem is to generate the same thing with a basic hard-coded lambda expression, in order to make a simple and readable test for automatic generation. I update my question with a simple fiddle, as you ask.

Comment: @PaulDS: Rather than a fiddle, please include the example in the question itself. But basically I suspect that a helper method is the best you'll get here.